# Compile errors using std::bind in gcc 4.7

Tags: c++11

I am having a lot of trouble using `std::bind` in various places of my code. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, so I assume I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

As far as I understand, the following basic use of `std::bind` should work fine:

```
#include <functional>

int foo(int a, int b){ return a+b; }

int main(){

    using namespace std::placeholders;

    // works
    auto bar_auto=std::bind(foo,1,_2);

    // compile error
    std::function<int(int)> bar_fun=std::bind(foo,1,_2);

    int quux=1;
    // compile error
    std::function<int(int)> bar_fun_lvalue=std::bind(foo,quux,_2);

}
```

Surely the type of `bar_auto` is `std::function<int(int)>` (type of `foo` with 1 `int` argument bound), so why does `bar_fun` fail to compile? I included `bar_fun_lvalue` because some googling showed me that [rvalues used to be problematic](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35569). but this didn't fix anything.

It resembles [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52612), but that's so old I don't expect it to be relevant.

gcc's output is not particularly enlightening:

> In file included from bindnew.cpp:1:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional: In instantiation of ‘static _Res
>   std::_Function_handler<_Res(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const
>   std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Res = int; _Functor =
>   std::_Bind))(int, int)>; _ArgTypes =
>   {int}]’: /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:2298:6:   required from
>   ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename
>   std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value),
>   std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor =
>   std::_Bind))(int, int)>; _Res = int;
>   _ArgTypes = {int}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function::_Useless]’
>   bindnew.cpp:15:52:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1912:40: error: no match for call to
>   ‘(std::_Bind))(int, int)>) (int)’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1140:11: note: candidates are:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1211:2: note: template _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result =
>   _Result; _Functor = int (*)(int, int); _Bound_args = {int, std::_Placeholder<2>}] /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1211:2: note:
>   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1206:35: error: cannot convert
>   ‘std::_No_tuple_element’ to ‘int’ in argument passing
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1225:2: note: template _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...};
>   _Result = _Result; _Functor = int (*)(int, int); _Bound_args = {int, std::_Placeholder<2>}] /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1225:2: note:
>   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1219:35: error: cannot convert
>   ‘std::_No_tuple_element’ to ‘int’ in argument passing
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1239:2: note: template _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...};
>   _Result = _Result; _Functor = int (*)(int, int); _Bound_args = {int, std::_Placeholder<2>}] /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1239:2: note:
>   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1233:35: error: cannot convert
>   ‘std::_No_tuple_element’ to ‘int’ in argument passing
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1253:2: note: template _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args
>   ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = int (*)(int, int); _Bound_args =
>   {int, std::_Placeholder<2>}] /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1253:2:
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1247:35: error: cannot convert
>   ‘std::_No_tuple_element’ to ‘int’ in argument passing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The placeholder position objects (e.g. when you use `_2`) is not the position of the argument in the function you call, but a placeholder for the argument in the created callable object. Instead always start with `_1` and increase.

So:

```
auto bar_auto=std::bind(foo,1,_1);
```

etc.

---

This means you can switch the arguments in the object created by `std::bind` by simply doing like

```
auto bar_auto=std::bind(foo,_2,_1);
```

When you "call" the `bar_auto` object, the first argument will be the second argument to `foo`, and the second argument in the call will be the first argument to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. It would have been helpful to get compiler warnings for `bar_auto`. Is there any reason such a dumb mistake on my part does not trigger a warning?

Comment: @MarcClaesen Well, it kind of does, with that long and unreadable error. :)

Comment: That dump was not about `bar_auto`, though. I guess there are no warnings because the resulting functions of `std::bind` may have an arbitrary number of arguments, so there is no way to assess whether a given placeholder is out of place (`_2` in my case).

Answer (score 4):

The `_2` placeholder means to use second argument of the *returned functor*. Therefore the type of

```
std::bind(foo,1,_2)
```

is not `std::function<int(int)>` but

```
std::function<int(unspecified_type, int)>
```

To get `std::function<int(int)>`, use

```
std::bind(foo, 1, _1)
//                ^^
```